# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error reading entity from input stream while reading List of an Object in Java

Tags: java, jax-rs, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard. I am trying to use Response to read a class that returns a list of an Object. I have tried using Generic Type and read comments of people who have similar issues but I still have the same error message on hitting the endpoint.

This is the method that calls the api.

```
public List<InactiveAgentsDto> fetchAgentsUnderAggregator(String aggregatorId, String token) throws RecordNotFoundException, IOException {
        String url = this.baseUrl+"/api/v1/users/aggregator/agent/" + aggregatorId;
        Response response = client.target(url).request().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token).get();
        
        if(response.getStatus() == 200){
            List<InactiveAgentsDto> allAgents = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<InactiveAgentsDto>>(){});
            return allAgents;
        }
        throw new RecordNotFoundException(response.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase());
    }
```

This is the error that I have.

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error reading entity from input stream
```

I have also tried this

```
 return response.readEntity(new ArrayList<InactiveAgentsDto>().getClass());
```

I get the same error message as above.

on logging String.class, I get the desired data that I need.

```
log.info("This is the error message {}", response.readEntity(String.class));
```

This prints the list of data to the console. Still wondering what I am doing wrong.

This is the content of inactiveAgentsDTO

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public classInactiveAgentsDto {

    private String agentId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String state;
    private String aggregatorId;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private BigDecimal cashOutAmount;
    private long cashOutCount;
    private Types.AgentTransactionStatus status;
}
```

I have taken out the imports.

Comment: *What* is the error reading from the input stream?  There is almost certainly more information.  And is `InactiveAgentsDto` [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html)?

Comment: The Object is Serializable. There is no other error message apart from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fix. I created a new class that contains a List of inactive agents. The class is called AllAgentsInfo.

```
public class AllAgentsInfo {
    private List<InactiveAgentsDto> data;
}
```

Then I had to rewrite the method to this

```
public AllAgentsInfo fetchAgentsUnderAggregator(String aggregatorId, String token) throws RecordNotFoundException,
            IOException {
        String url = this.baseUrl+"/api/v1/users/aggregator/agent/" + aggregatorId;
        Response response = client.target(url).request().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token).get();

        String stringEntity = response.readEntity(String.class);

        ResponseDto responseDto  = new ObjectMapper().readValue(stringEntity, ResponseDto.class);

        if(Objects.isNull(responseDto) || !responseDto.isStatus()){
            String message = Objects.isNull(responseDto) || Objects.isNull(responseDto.getMessage()) ? "Unable to get agent information" : responseDto.getMessage();
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(message);
        }
        return  new ObjectMapper().convertValue(responseDto, AllAgentsInfo.class);

    }
```

This fixed my problem. In case you are wondering what the ResponseDTO.

```
public class ResponseDto<T> {
    private String message;
    private String responseCode;
    private boolean status;
    private T data;

    public ResponseDto(String message, String responseCode, boolean status, T data) {
        this.message = message;
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```